# Search keywords in pdf file opened in UIWebview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uiwebview, share-extension

Using web view to open and display pdf file. Actually this is an extension app. I am fetching pdf file from iphone mail app in the attachments using share extension. So far i am able to open pdf in web view but want to perform search on the pdf after opening in webview. Spent a day already but no luck so far. Tried using this link [Search to highlight text in PDF using UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856076/search-to-highlight-text-in-pdf-using-uiwebview)

Kindly guide me. Hope i made my question clear.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20131122162015/http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184 try this , But this isn't opening file in web-view.You can download file and than apply search.

Comment: https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/ this is a good library for search in pdf , You can check this.

Comment: But it doean't support swift any swift version i have not found of this library so far

Comment: Did you get any solutions?